# How to modify style to work in all browsers

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t4uujehb/1/

HTML:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div class="theNum numOnly" style="float: left; cursor: pointer;">
        45
    </div>
    <div class="theNum" style="float: left;">
        <span>Provider(s) failed to update</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

FireFox:

[image]

Chrome/IE 9/10:

[image]

How can I modify my CSS so styling is same in Chrome and IE (Or as close as possible for IE)

Comment: you are using -moz prefix for radial gradient, so that will not work in webkit browsers.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and get `autoprefixer` configured. You'll thank yourself later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must generate gradient also for other browsers (vendor prefixes) with tool such as [ColorZilla](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). I tried and result is:

```
.theNum
{
    background: #ededed; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 0%, #dedede 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#ededed), color-stop(100%,#dedede)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 0%,#dedede 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 0%,#dedede 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ededed 0%,#dedede 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ededed 0%,#dedede 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ededed', endColorstr='#dedede',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
```

Comment: The `hover` is the main change I would like to make. But let me check it out. Thanks. +1